# Javascript form validation doesn't return anything

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have an HTML form with some fields and a javascript validation that checks them, my problem is that js doesn't return anything, and although the fields are filled not propertly the submit sends.

Here an example of my code:

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="action.php" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
       <table>
          <tr>
             <td>
                <label class="standard_text">
                   E-mail
                </label>
             </td>
             <td><input class="textarea" required type="email" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="E-mail"></label></td>
             <td><div class="check_icon icon_yes" style="display:none" id="mail_ok_icon"></div></td>
             <td><div class="check_icon icon_no" style="display:none" id="mail_no_icon"></div></label></td>
             <td><div class="check_message" style="display:none" id="mail_message"><label class="important_text">The email format is not correct!</label></div></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       <input class="button_submit" type="submit" name="send_form" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function validate_form(){

    //email var
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var mail_ok_icon = document.getElementById("mail_ok_icon");
    var mail_no_icon = document.getElementById("mail_no_icon");
    var mail_message = document.getElementById("mail_message");

    //email format check
    if ((/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(mail)) || mail=="" || mail==null) {
        mail_no_icon.style.display="block";
        mail_message.style.display="block"; 
        return(false);

    } else {
        mail_ok_icon.style.display="block";
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to display elements depending on the javascript checking and also trying to don't let the user send the information if the checking of all the fields are not correct.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: The `else` part does not return anything. Which would make the function implicitly return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code -:

In the original code the email input had `required` and `type="email"` which never called the javascript code in the first instance.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="action.php" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
       <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label class="standard_text">
               E-mail
              </label>
            </td>
            <td><input class="textarea"  name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="E-mail"></label></td>
            <td><div class="check_icon icon_yes" style="display:none" id="mail_ok_icon"></div></td>
            <td><div class="check_icon icon_no" style="display:none" id="mail_no_icon"></div></label></td>
            <td><div class="check_message" style="display:none" id="mail_message"><label class="important_text">The email format is not correct!</label></div></td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       <input class="button_submit" type="submit" name="send_form" value="Register"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is the js code -:

```
 function validate_form() {
    //email var
    var mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    var mail_ok_icon = document.getElementById("mail_ok_icon");
    var mail_no_icon = document.getElementById("mail_no_icon");
    var mail_message = document.getElementById("mail_message");

    //email format check
    if (!(/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(mail)) || mail=="" || mail==null) {
        mail_no_icon.style.display="block";
        mail_message.style.display="block"; 
        console.log('hi');        
        return false;
    } else {
        mail_ok_icon.style.display="block";
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AleixGalletSegarra @nitin Removing the `type="email"` or `required` is not advisable as these are HTML standards and will work for validation as expected even if javascript was disabled. You only need to change the js logic of `!` before the regex check and the `return` statements to correct your code.

Comment: @AleixGalletSegarra If worked then you might accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks, will try this ;)

@Nitin Misra "!Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"